# CSS Horizontal Dropdown positioning

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am trying to implement a horizontal navigation menu with a horizontal dropdown menu. I am trying to figure out how to center the horizontal dropdown text so it sits in the center of the navigation container so the user doesn't have to move the mouse far left to reach the links.

```
    <style type="text/css">
#nav-container {
    padding: 4px;
    width: 900px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #CCC;
}
#navbar {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#navbar li {
    padding: 6px;
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}
#navbar li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width: 900px;
}
#navbar li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="nav-container">
<ul id="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        <ul>

            <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">World</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Peace</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Love</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Smiles</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cries</a></li>

         </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Homer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Peter</a></li>
         </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Giggity</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fapping</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Napster</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Myspace</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is rough code just to show an example, here is a [live example](http://phdzine.net/dev/nav/mynav4.php) of the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of relative-absolute positioning should do the trick. I tried adding these two rules and that seemed to work:

```
#navbar li {
    position: relative;
}

#navbar li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 24px; /* must me same as the height of parent li +/- a couple of pixels */
}
```

That seems to do the trick.